# Can't use tezos-client after restoring from snapshot

Tags: tezos-client, docker, snapshots, bootstrapping

I normally run these commands to start up a tezos babylonnet node:

```
./babylonnet.sh start --rpc-port 127.0.0.1:8732
./babylonnet.sh shell

tezos-node identity generate
tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1 --history-mode experimental-rolling
```

I was having issues and it crashed, so I deleted everything and tried to restore from a public snapshot from here: https://lambsonacid.nl/

using these commands:

```
./babylonnet.sh snapshot import <FULL_PATH_TO_FOLDER>/BM3NxjtuL67aWvHoEqcV9xcD27DeQsKoRWCEaVx64tdf19AUJbY_FULL
./babylonnet.sh start --rpc-port 127.0.0.1:8732
./babylonnet.sh shell

tezos-node identity generate
tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1 --history-mode experimental-rolling
```

I didn't get any errors, the last command is spitting out output saying its bootstrapping and validating blocks. Its been going for 1 hour. Again no errors.

Now in another terminal I can't run anything from `tezos-client` getting these errors:

[image]

`http://node:8732` doesn't look right it should be `127.0.0.1`?

I tried running it from postman too and it refused connection. Have I missed a step?

**EDIT:**

For anyone else facing the same issue, running:

```
./babylonnet.sh stop
./babylonnet.sh start   # Without --rpc-port
```

Got me back up and running for now. But i'm unable to use `--rpc-port` to expose rpc outside of the docker. It will unblock me for now, but will block me again for experimenting on my local network